# JDialog blanks out inside a swingnode in javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have javafx application and a swing application. I have added the swing application inside a swing node of javafx application.

Initially it all works fine. But the child dialogs (JDialogs) in the swing application when opened blanks out with just a white color. The components winside the Jdialog starts rendering when hover or when tried to resize the dialog using mouse.

I have already tried all the below options one by one and also combined. But it doesn't seem to work. Please help.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            m_dialog.setVisible(true);
            m_dialog.requestFocus();
            m_dialog.repaint();
            m_dialog.update(m_dialog.getGraphics()); 
            m_dialog.validate();
        });
```

JDialog when it opens up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2cQV.png)

Jdialog on resizing it using mouse:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy62r.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62692194/edit) to add a [mre] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: .. and stick to java naming conventions ..